# Scatterplot colour by distance to neighbour

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distance

I'm trying to create a plot from a tSNE result by colouring points based on their neighbourhood density - that is the number of neighours around the point and the distance to the neighbours.

Given a matrix of tSNE result coordinates:

```
            [,1]       [,2]
  [1,] -4.2060515  3.1718312
  [2,] -4.2671476  5.6677296
  [3,] -3.1792470  3.5504695
  [4,] -3.2507526  4.7510075
  [5,] -4.5662531  3.3866132
  [6,] -5.0863544  3.1760014
  [7,] -4.7380256  5.5291478
  [8,] -5.0510355  5.0373626
  [9,] -4.3288679  4.3316772
 [10,] -5.2947188  4.6130757
[etc,] ...         ...
```

I want to be able to colour the points according to the criteria above.

But so far all I can get is this, which is this just the average Euclidean distance but that's not correct:

[image: this]

Ideally, I like something that looks similar to crude mockup where points that are closer together are coloured darker than points which have fewer local neighbours: [image: this]

```
d <- dist(best.tsne, method = "euclidean")`
d.scaled <- quick.scale(apply(as.matrix(d), 2, sum),
                        floor = 0, ceiling = 1)
ii <- cut(d.scaled,
          breaks = seq(min(d.scaled), max(d.scaled), len = 100),
          include.lowest = TRUE)
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue"))(99)[ii]
```

I'm fine with assigning colours etc. just need to be able to calculate the score for the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods, but the most common is to use the two-dimensional kernel or generate a measure like the one you have made but adapting it better to the data.

I give you some examples:

1 - Bidimensional kernel:

```
# With kde2d {MASS}
library(MASS)
attach(geyser)
plot(duration, waiting, xlim = c(0.5,6), ylim = c(40,100))
f1 <- kde2d(duration, waiting, n = 50, lims = c(0.5, 6, 40, 100))
image(f1)
```

2 - Measure ad-hoc (1):

```
# Trimean 20%
apply(as.matrix(d), 2, mean, trim = 0.8)
```

3 - Measure ad-hoc (2):

```
# Normalized inverse distance
apply(as.matrix(1/((1+d)/max(1+d))), 2, mean)
```

Regards!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, this isn't exactly what I was looking for. 


Method 1 returns this [plot](https://i.imgur.com/JEr56lG.png) 


Method 2 returns this [plot](https://i.imgur.com/ilk0M6O.png)


Method 3 returns a [sequence of infinites](https://i.imgur.com/YeNfMBl.png)

Comment: If I like more details about what you're looking for, maybe I'll help you, I've worked for many years with MDS and geostatistics, and I've had this problem many times. Your graph is very different from the other because the average of the distances is very influenced by the great distances, so you only find density in the central cluster.

Comment: Method 3 is incorrect, as.matrix(1/((1+d)/max(1+d)))

Comment: With your correction, Method 3 works exactly like I'd want. Thank you.